# Multiple print statements in a return

Tags: python, string

How would I store the below function, `careers`, in a variable for later use?

```
jobs = ('Cook', 'Vet', 'Doctor', 'Pilot')
def careers():
    print("Heres a list of jobs\n")

    for j in jobs:
        print("This person is a " + j + ".")
    
    print("\nAre you interested in any of these as careers?")

post = careers()
```

When I attempt to `print(post())` (the above variable I assigned the function to) the output is `None`. I understand I should be using return to output the results of a function but am having trouble finding out to use return in a function with multiple print statements that need to stay in below format.

```
Heres a list of jobs

This person is a Cook.
This person is a Vet.
This person is a Doctor.
This person is a Pilot.

Are you interested in any of these as careers?
```

Comment: build up a string by setting an initial value then appending more text to it.  Part of that text can be "\r\n" (carriage return line feed)

Comment: What do you expect/want the function to return? The string you printed? Or the user's response to the question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist just the string I printed

Comment: I just answered this exact question under different guise earlier today. Since the other question has what in my opinion is a very comprehensive answer giving you three possible options, I'm going to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to understand the concept of "return" in python , if you want to get a variable from a funnction , you can return it from that function and you will get it when/whereever you call that function
here is a fixed version of your code

```
jobs = ('Cook', 'Vet', 'Doctor', 'Pilot')
def careers():
    output_of_careers = ""
    output_of_careers += output_of_careers +"Heres a list of jobs\n\n"
    for j in jobs:
        output_of_careers = output_of_careers +"This person is a " + j + ".\n"
    
    output_of_careers = output_of_careers +"\nAre you interested in any of these as careers?"
    return output_of_careers
post = careers()
print(post)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Exactly what I needed. I wasn't sure how to append multiple lines to a variable in Python and you answered it. I really appreciate your time on this!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you actually want to store the function `careers`, you need to assign the function `careers` (note the absence of brackets) to `post`, not the result of calling `careers()`.

The reason you're getting `None` is that if you don't return anything from a function in Python, you get `None` (though I'm surprised you're not getting a `TypeError` instead by trying to call `None()`).

Comment: This does not actually answer the question...

Comment: No it doesn't considering the extra clarification given